# How can I rewrite this sentence without repeating of a word

Tags: sentence-construction, repetition

> The **features** range from DOM-level **features** to more complex visual **features** and densitometric **features** like text density or link density.

How can I rewrite this sentence with leas "features".

Can I factor out "**feature**" and say:

> The features range from DOM-level to more complex visual and densitometric features, like text density or link density.

Features are characteristics of webpage elements. DOM-level features are like heading, paragraph, divisions,.. etc. (in HTML source), visual features are like text color, back color, font weight, ..., densitometric features are like the number of links or words in a section.

Comment: Any time there is a struggle in sentence construction over a single word, in terms of placement or repetition, I tend to encourage the author to re-evaluate the entire *sentence* to solve the problem. In this case, could you provide a bit more context for the "features" being described? It might help reveal a superior restructuring.

Comment: What is the problem ? I mean if "x-feature" cannot be abridged to "x", so you must repeat them

Comment: @DavidW I did...

Comment: What is text density? Dense = hard to understand?

Comment: @TRomano the degree to which an area is filled with words.

Comment: The core problem here IMO is the "range from...to....to" structure, which is just another way of saying to the reader: "here's some miscellaneous stuff".

Answer (score 1):

> The features range from DOM-level (features) to more complex visual (features) and densitometric features like text density or link density.

Leave out the () then you get:

> The **features** range from DOM-level to more complex visual and densitometric **features**, like text density or link density.

Comma optional.

Comment: You answered something that I was going to ask. (note the revision), it seems I can factor the "feature" out.

Answer (score 0):

I really think you can just drop them. Or you can replace them with component/function/etc.

How about this:
"The features range from DOM-level **components** to more complex visual **details** and densitometric **functions** like text density or link density."

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I'm only marginally satisfied with this answer, but I will offer it nonetheless:

> The features range from the DOM-level, such as paragraphs and
>   headings, to the complex, such as text color and font weight, and also
>   include the densitometric, such as link or text density.

Answer (score 0):

> The features range from DOM-level to visual and densitometric ones.  The visual features are complex [example here], and the densitometric [is this really the right word?] ones include link and text density.